# Find a new point with the shortest distance to any point of a set of given points

Tags: geometry

There are N given points on a plane.

I would like to find the point which has the shortest possible distance to any of the given points.

So the distance between the new point and its most farest away of the given points should be minimized.

is this a standard problem where i get get some theory or so?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you think about it, finding the closest point to every point on the plane can be done by calculating the center of the polygon created by the points.
Now we can talk about a standard geometry problem of finding a polygon centroid, which can be solved easily:
I guess you have y-axis and x-axis for your plane. So just find the mean of all the points in the plane. divide the sum of the x's by the number of points and then do same thing for the y value. You now have the right (x,y) values for your center.

I hope it helped you.

You can also find some more explanation here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#Centroid_of_polygon

Comment: Thanks but no.. That would only be true, if the points in X and Y are equally distributed. It would be for sure better to take the center of min/max values in X and center of min/max values in Y ...but that would only be best case for X and Y seperately. But I want to have best case of the shortest distance on the plane